# Missing commit after rebase

Tags: git, commit, rebase

Recently I ran into a very peculiar situation with GIT rebase.

I branched off of the master branch quite long ago and was working on my feature code.
The GIT history looked something like this:

```
A-B-C-D-E (master)
     \F1-F2-F3-F4 (feature)
```

No merge commits on feature branch - just plain simple commits.

Now, when I used rebase to update my code by doing:

```
(feature) $> git rebase master
```

Now, lo and behold in my git history I could see only 3 out of 4 commits of my feature branch.
The middle one `F3` was missing

```
A-B-C-D-E-F1'-F2'-F4' (feature)
```

The F3 commit contained just a simple one-line switch, which I was able to quickly detect, however, what would happen if it was a bigger change, or more difficult to find?

I tried to use:

```
git rebase master --allow-empty
```

but the effect was the same - only 3 commits.

I performed an experiment by manually running:

```
> git checkout master
> git cherry-pick F1
> git cherry-pick F2
> git cherry-pick F3
> git cherry-pick F4
```

Now the effect was that **ALL** of the commits were successfully applied on the master branch - as expected.

Additional info:
When I ran

```
git merge master
```

All the changes contained in F1-F2-F3-F4 commits were reflected in the code. (the flag change in F3 included)

Can someone explain to me what happened there?

What other experiments can I run to figure out what went wrong?

Comment: please demonstrate, don't describe, what happened. I.e. `git reset --hard <PREVIOUS HEAD>` and show the output of `git log` and `git rebase origin/master` or equivalent.

Comment: To see if a patch-ID-equivalent commit was in the upstream, use `git cherry` or `git log --left-right --cherry-mark`. Read through [the `git cherry` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) for an example command. (BTW I'm of the opinion that rebase, both interactive and non-interactive, should by default **warn you** when it detects a cherry-picked copy to omit, since this can go awry. But it's pretty rare for it to actually go wrong: it would be interesting to see what happened in your actual repository.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git rebase` compares the changes (yes, the changes!) introduced by each of the commits to be rebased with the changes that are in the upstream since the rebased branch was forked. It looks like one of your commits `D`, `E` looks exactly the same as one of your rebased commits.

See [git patch-id](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id).

Comment: Thanks, @j6t! I thought git rebase is using cherry-pick under the hood, but this case clearly shows that it's not, because cherry-pick applies the missing commit

Comment: You can try `git rebase -m`; it uses cherry-pick under the hood. But it would still first check the patch id and possibly omit the commit anyway.

Comment: exactly as you said, I tried `rebase -m` and still one offending commit is missing.
Manually cherry-picking the desired range works as **I** expect. The missing piece in my knowledge was this `git patch-id`. I will experiment with it.
Thank you!

Comment: @paroxyzm: rebase *does* use cherry-pick (some of the time, or all of the time if you force it to via command line options), but it removes patch-ID-equivalent commits *first*, when it builds up the list of commits to copy.